# How does React batch setState when mixing object and callback approach?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

According to the docs, React batches setState if it is provided with a callback

```
this.setState(prevState => {value: prevState + 1 })
```

Now, assume we have an instance method that does several setState calls

```
reset() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({value: prevState.initialValue}));
  this.setState({initialValue: null});
}
```

Since we don't need access to state values in the second setState, we don't have to use functional setState. In this situation, does React still batch the functional setState at a later point in time (and potentially execute the object setState first)? Or would it maintain the execution order?

Answer (score 0):

Both `setState` with a function argument (`updater`) and with an object argument will apply changes to the state object synchronously. The point is that it applies changes not to the `this.state` object but to the pending 'next' state object (this is my terminology, not from docs). And `updater` gives us the ability to access this pending 'next' state we're updating.

Consider this example:

```
// this.state.value === 0
this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 });
// pendingState.value === 1
this.setState(pendingState => ({ value: pendingState.value + 1 }));
// pendingState.value === 2
this.setState(pendingState => ({ value: pendingState.value + 2 }));
// pendingState.value === 4
this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 });
// pendingState.value === 1
```

Hopefully this helps. Same example in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/2p6j2mxnyj